# Why does save method needs to use an already existing EntityManager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-scheduled

Recently I faced an issue regarding updating entities from a `@Scheduled` method where it would fail with the exception `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance` even though it would work seamless when invoked from a `@RestController` method. This is the relevant example:

**The offending method (other parts of the class omitted for brevity):**

```java
@Service
public class AnonymizationService
{
    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public Result anonymizeItemsOlderThan(int days) {
        List<Item> data = itemRepository.findAllByCreatedDateBeforeAndAnonymizationDateIsNull(Instant.now().minus(days, ChronoUnit.DAYS));

        List<String> itemsAnonymized = new ArrayList<>(data.size());

        data.forEach(item -> itemsAnonymized.add(itemRepository.save(item.anonymize()).getRequestId()));

        return Result.builder().anonymizedItems(itemsAnonymized).build();
    }
}
```

**The `@RestController` caller (again most stuff omitted):**

```java
@RestController
public class DataAnonymizationAPI
{
  private final AnonymizationService anonymizationService;

  @PutMapping(path = "${datadeletion.path:/anonymize}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Result> anonymizeAll(@Valid DataDeletionRules dataDeletionRules) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(anonymizationService.anonymizeItemsOlderThan(dataDeletionRules.getMinimunAge()));
  }
}
```

Again, this works just fine when used like above. The problem happens when `AnonymizationService#anonymizeItemsOlderThan()` is instead invoked from the following `@Scheduled` method:

```java
@Component
public class DataDeletionTasks
{

  private final AnonymizationService anonymizationService;
  private final DataAnonymizationProperties properties;

  @Scheduled(cron = "${datadeletion.anonymization.schedule}")
  public void anonymizeItemsPeriodically() {
    anonymizationService.anonymizeItemsOlderThan(properties.getAnonymization().getMinAge());
  }
}
```

In this case it fails with the exception mentioned above (`org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException`).

Upon changing the log level to DEBUG and carefully analyzing it, nothing unexpected happens:

- When the method is invoked from the `@RestController` an existing `EntityManager` is used and a transaction created:

```
o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1702787226<open>)] for JPA transaction
o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
```

- When the method is invoked from the `@Scheduled` method a new `EntityManager` is created:

```
o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(644498403<open>)] for JPA transaction
```

Naturally, my instinct was to add `@Transactional` to the `Anonymization#anonymizeItemsOlderThan()` method which immediately solved it, but why?

Why does it work in one case and not in the other? Why does the `saveAndFlush()` must be performed using the same `EntityManager` used to retrieve the entity in the first place?

This situation made me think my knowledge is flawed on a very basic level, but somehow couldn't find a clear explanation to it. In any case feel free to point me towards relevant literature that might help me.

Comment: ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/34641670/592355

Comment: @xerx593 thanks, even though it looks like it doesn't exactly answer my question, it made me realize that my question might be incorrectly formulated.

So would I be correct in assuming that the "catch" here is that the `fetch` and the `save` calls should use the same entity manager (which in fact `@Transactional` fixes)?

Comment: ..sry, i deleted my previous comment, a la: "The exception/behavior would be (more) reasonable, if: `@RestController` *is* `@Transactional` ..and your `@Service/@Scheduled` *not*. ;)" (fix: make service( OR scheduled(!?)) transactional)